# Can I outsource a mat-form-field as a custom component or directive?

Tags: angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have this form field:

```
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput type="password" placeholder="password" formControlName="password" autocomplete="new-password">

        <mat-hint align="end">Must have one letter, and one number</mat-hint>
        <mat-error *ngIf="password.invalid && password.touched" class="has-text-danger">
            That password sucks...
        </mat-error>

    </mat-form-field>
```

And I want to use it as a custom component like:

```
<password-form-field formControlName="password"></password-form-field>
```

Giving the formControlName in the parent component. Is something like this possible?

The reason for this is that I would like to use this  in many other components..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should implement [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) in  your `password-form-field` component in order to be able to use `password-form-field` with `formControlName`. Here is an example;

https://medium.com/@majdasab/implementing-control-value-accessor-in-angular-1b89f2f84ebf

.....

Alternatively you can achieve same result by using `formControl` directive instead of `formControlName` as follows:

First you should add an `@Input` to `password-form-field`

```
@Component({
    selector: "password-form-field",
    templateUrl: "./password-form-field.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./password-form-field.component.scss"]
})
export class PasswordFormFieldComponent {
    @Input() formCtrl: FormControl;

    constructor() {}
}
```

then use it in your `password-form-field.component.html` as follows:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput type="password" placeholder="password" [formControl]="formCtrl" autocomplete="new-password" />
  <mat-hint align="end">Must have one letter, and one number</mat-hint>
  <mat-error *ngIf="password.invalid && password.touched" class="has-text-danger">
    That password sucks...
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Finally you can use it anywhere as follows;

```
/** if password is defined as a standalone FormControl */
<password-form-field [formCtrl]="password"></password-form-field>
```

OR

```
/** if password is defined in a FormGroup named myFormGroup  */
<password-form-field [formCtrl]="myFormGroup.get('password')"></password-form-field>
```

Comment: Thanks. I found myself doing in exactly that way.. working!

Comment: As a next step I would suggest to take the form field out to the parent form and make your custom form control as a "Custom form field control". That will give you more control from the parent forms. https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control